# Plotly axis label format with Plotly.js

Tags: plotly

I have numerical axis labels in the form `12345`. Plotly is formatting these numbers in the form `12.3k`.

I'd like to be able to show the unaltered numbers, but so far have been unable to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found that each axis can take a tickformat value which defines the appearance of the ticks.

```
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        tickformat : ":04,2f"
    },
    yaxis: {
        tickformat : ":04,2f"
    }
};
```